# Do I need to wrap a django update in a transaction?

Tags: django, django-models, transactions, django-orm

Suppose I am running an update of several model objects in django:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(name="abc").update(name="xyz")
```

Do I need to wrap this in `transaction.atomic`? Is there anything bad that will happen if I don't?

Answer (score 0):

Django's default transaction model is to commit to the db automatically. This means if there is an exception after some changes have been committed, but before all changes have been committed, you could end up with problems- or not. That depends on exactly what it is you're trying to do. Is that a potential problem, based on your own code? Is there a risk of an error happening, and if so, would it be a problem that some objects would have been updated but not others?

If so, you can prevent this by using the @transaction.atomic decorator (for a function) or by wrapping a specific code fragment with `with transaction.atomic():`. This will roll back changes to the db in event of an error. Just to be ultra-safe I guess you could always use atomic transactions, but do you need to?